# use scalaz's === for adt's

Tags: scala, typeclass, scalaz7

I have just started to learn scalaz from [eugene's blog post](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/typeclasses+102.html). I am trying to use === in my code but it returns a compile error
    `value === is not a member of object Red`

Here's is my code

```
import scalaz._

sealed trait TrafficLight
case object Red extends TrafficLight
case object Yellow extends TrafficLight
case object Green extends TrafficLight

object Equality {

import Scalaz._

def eqInstance[A](f: (A,A) => Boolean): Equal[A] = new Equal[A]{
    def equal(a1: A, a2: A): Boolean = f(a1,a2)    
}

def trafficLightEqualFunction(a1: TrafficLight, a2: TrafficLight): Boolean = (a1, a2) match {
    case (Red, Red) => true
    case (Yellow, Yellow) => true
    case (Green, Green) => true
    case _ => false
}

implicit val trafficLightEqual: Equal[TrafficLight] = eqInstance(trafficLightEqualFunction)

def main(args: Array[String]){
    println(Red === Red)
}
```

}

Comment: Works for me on scala 2.11.7 and scalaz 7.1.3, produces: `true`. What version are you using?

Comment: Can't make it work for ScalaZ 7.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what his blog complains. The type of `Red` is `Red.type` and there is no instance of `scalaz.Equal` for this type because Equal is invariant, so despite:

`Red <: TrafficLight`

it **doesn't follow**

`Equal[Red] <: Equal[TrafficLight]`.

You can amend that by making Scala see Red as TrafficLight:

```
println((Red:TrafficLight) === (Red:TrafficLight))
```

Comment: Yes...I got that...made it work by doing `Red.asInstanceOf[TrafficLight] === Red.asInstanceOf[TrafficLight]`
But, what is the solution? Both `Red:TrafficLight === Red.TrafficLight` and `Red.asInstanceOf[TrafficLight] === Red.asInstanceOf[TrafficLight]` looks bad

Comment: I like the solution he shows in the post: have you own constructors like `val red:TrafficLight = Red`.